# How can I move a vertex and maintain its distance from another?

Tags: modeling

Is this possible? Basically the other vertex would be like its pivot.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. In edit mode, select the pivot vertex and press the space bar to bring up the command selector dialog. Choose "Snap Cursor to Active" to set the 3D cursor to the position of this vertex.

Then press the <kbd>.</kbd> key to set the cursor as the centre of rotation. You can then select the vertex you want to move and press <kbd>R</kbd> twice to enter free rotation mode (or just once to rotate in the current view). Either way, the distance of the selected vertex from the centre of rotation will remain constant.

Comment: Question, why when I use "Snap Cursor to Active" it doesn't look like it's exactly on the vertex sometimes?

Comment: You might have selected more than one vertex by accident. Look at the top of the 3D view. If you only have one vertex selected, it should say something like `Verts 1/999`, where `999` corresponds to the total number of vertices and `1` is the number of selected vertices.

Comment: It does say that. http://i.imgur.com/j2B0fur.png

Comment: Hmm, beats me. Might be worth asking another question about that.